# Amazon EC2 file structure / web app with separate Python backend?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm currently running a t2.micro instance on EC2 right now. I have the html/web interface side of it working, along with a MySQL database.

The site allows users to register and stores them in the DB via a PHP script.

I want there to be an actual Python application that queries the MySQL database and returns user data, to then be executed in a Python script.

What I cannot find is whether I host this Python application as a totally separate instance or if it can exist on the same instance, in a different directory. I ultimately just need to query the database, which makes me thing it must exist on the same instance.

Could someone please provide some guidance?

Let me just be clear: this is *not* a Python web app. This Python backend is entirely separate except making queries against the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either approach is possible, but there are pros & cons to each.

**Running separate Python app on the same server:**

Pros:

- Setting up local access to the database is fairly simple
- Only need to handle backups or making snapshots, etc. for a single instance

Cons:

- Harder to scale up individual pieces if you need more memory, processing power, etc. in the future

**Running the Python app on a separate server:**

Pros:

- Separate pieces means you can scale up & down the hardware each piece is running on, according to their individual needs
- If you're using all micro instances, you get more resources to work with, without any extra costs (assuming you're still meeting all the other 'free tier eligible' criteria)

Cons:

- In general, more pieces == more time spent on configuration, administration tasks, etc.
- You have to open up the database to non-local access

  - Simplest: open up the database to access from anywhere (e.g. all remote IP addresses), and have the Python app log in via the internet
  - Somewhat safer, more complex: set the Python app server up with an [elastic IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html), open up the database to access only from that address
  - Much safer, more complex: set up your own [virtual private cloud (VPC)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Introduction.html), and allow connections to the database only from within the VPC. You'd have to configure public access for each of the servers for whatever public traffic you'll have, presumably ports 80 and/or 443.